# Distinct LINQ Statement - Select Group where Entity doesn't exist

Tags: c#, sql, linq, radgrid

I currently have a LINQ statement that returns an IQueryable to be displayed into a Telerik RadGrid. This statement is set to pull Records that match the Period inputted, and also have the "Premium" Column set to true. It then selects the EmployeeID & ProjectID distinctly using the GroupBy property.

These columns are then displayed in the RadGrid, along with a "PremiumCode" column. 
Currently my statement works to display ALL of the records that meet the top credentials (Employee Name, Project, Premium Code), but my end Goal is to *pull only those Records which **DONT** already have a "PremiumCode" assigned to the Project for that particular Employee*.

```
public static IQueryable GetEmptyPremiums(string Period)
    {
        DataContext Data = new DataContext();
        var PR = (from c in Data.System_Times
                  where c.Period == Period && c.Premium == true
                  orderby c.System_Employee.LName
                  select c).GroupBy(s => s.EmployeeID & s.ProjectID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());

        return PR;
    }
```

Currently it is displaying properly, but every record is being displayed, not just the ones that require a PremiumCode.

[image]

Is there a way to re-work my LINQ statement to only include the records that **need** a PremiumCode?

**EDIT:**
Jay,
I have tried to modify your solution to fit my needs, but unfortunately with no success. Records in the Premium table are not added until a Premium Code is defined, therefore there will never be a null "PremiumCode".

To describe my end-goal a tad more clearly: I am looking to show the information in a grid like in the image above. The records shown will be the distinct Time records that have the bool value "Premium" checked as true but don't have a PremiumCode record in the Premium Table.

If the checked record has a matching record in the Premium table (EmployeeID, and ProjectID **matching**) then it **already possesses** a Premium Code set and will not need to be displayed in the Grid.

If the checked record has no matching record in the Premium table (EmployeeID, and ProjectID **not matching**) then it **requires** a PremiumCode and will need to be displayed in the Grid.

I believe this can be achieved with ".Any()" but I am having troubles aligning my Syntax and Logic to make this Grid display properly.

Comment: You haven't mentioned how the premium code is represented within the database or your model.

Comment: where c.Period == Period && c.Premium == true && !c.PremiumCode.HasValue -- is something like that what you are seeking?

Comment: The PremiumCode is located in it's own Table consisting of EmployeeID, ProjectID, PremiumCode, and a PremiumID. These are linked to an Employees Table, and Projects Table, respectively.  Andrew - that is along the lines of what I am looking for but I with no Relationships between my Times and Premium Table, I cannot simply use c.PremiumCode, and c.System_Premium.PremiumCode gives me errors with IntelliSense.

Comment: Lando, I added an update in response to the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
 DataContext Data = new DataContext();
 var projectsWithoutPremium = Data.Premiums.Where(p => p.PremiumCode == null)
                             .Select(p => p.ProjectId);
 var PR = (from c in Data.System_Times
          where c.Period == Period && c.Premium == true
                && projectsWithoutPremium.Contains(c.ProjectId)
          orderby c.System_Employee.LName
          select c).GroupBy(s => s.EmployeeID & s.ProjectID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());

 return PR;
```

#### update in response to question edit

```
DataContext Data = new DataContext();
var PR = (from c in Data.System_Times
             where c.Period == Period && c.Premium == true
                 && !Data.Premiums.Any(p => p.ProjectID == c.ProjectID && p.EmployeeID == c.ProjectID) 
             orderby c.System_Employee.LName select c)
             .GroupBy(s => s.EmployeeID & s.ProjectID)
             .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());

return PR;
```

Comment: This worked perfect! Hadn't thought of nesting a second LINQ statement, Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If premium code is a string, you might want to try adding something like `.Where(x => string.isNullOrEmpty(x.PremiumCode))` before the GroupBy clause.

Comment: Logically this would work (and wish it did), but since there is no link directly from my "Times" table to my "Premium" table, I cannot simply use x.PremiumCode, or x.System_Premium.PremiumCode.  I have my DB setup this way so that Each Employee, can have a different PremiumCode for each Job, not each record in the Times table.